# An easy way to program an Android keyboard layout app

Tags: android, keyboard, adk

I would like to program an android app that replaces the standard keyboard by one with the one-hand optimized [Coffee++](http://coffeeplusplus.z11.de/) keyboard layout.

What special problems would I have to face in the progress? I guess that such a project would go deep into the android core, cause the keyboard is such an essential thing.

Is it wise to start with the Android Developer Tools (ADT)—Eclipse Plugin as described in [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-your-first-android-app-2/)?

Or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

I am new to Android programming, but very firm in PHP, Mysql and javascript and I already use Eclipse for PHP

Answer (score 0):

> I guess that such a project would go deep into the android core, cause the keyboard is such an essential thing.

No. You can create an `InputMethodService` that is the implementation of your keyboard. There is a sample soft keyboard in your Android SDK installation (if you chose to download sample code from the SDK Manager), and there are open source input methods floating around as well, such as the Hacker's Keyboard. This `InputMethodService` is then distributed as part of an ordinary Android application, and the user can elect to activate your input method if the user chooses.

> Is it wise to start with the Android Developer Tools (ADT)—Eclipse Plugin as described in this tutorial?

That is a fine starting point. I would also recommend that you spend some time learning Java, then  developing ordinary Android apps, to get a feel for how Android works.

When you are ready to work on the `InputMethodService` itself, [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) can help guide you, and you are welcome to return here for more specific questions. However, bear in mind that writing a soft keyboard is not all that common, and so support resources for it may be a bit lacking.

Comment: I Tried to install The SDK in my eclipse 3.8 but it looks a bit strange: I cannot move any of the Elements (Form Widgets) into the right Phone-View. Is there a very basic tutorial, that explains this for a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

A soft keyboard in Android is called a InputMethod, and you don't have to go too deep to be able to create one. Creating a InputMethod is fairly straight forward especially if the keyboard is normal button kind.

You can check the following links to get a start : 
[Android's Official Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) or you can check out [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) tutorial too to get a head start.
I would also recommend downloading the source code for [LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/) keyboard available for the developers to tinker with.